# Open a link with a specified url and specified browser hidden with vbscript

Tags: vbscript

I want to convert this batch command

```
start msedge.exe --new-window "https://www.google.com/"
```

to a vbscript file so I can open it in hidden

I've tried this

```
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.Run """https://www.google.com/""", 0,TRUE
```

but it only opens on default browser and not open with new window

Any help?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of trying to replace the batch command, run the batch command via the script like this:

```
Option Explicit
Dim MyCommand, WshShell
MyCommand = "cmd /c start msedge.exe --new-window ""https://www.google.com/"""
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.Run MyCommand, 0, True
```

Comment: That's the way I'd do it.

Comment: What I mean is, I want to run msedge.exe hidden (not minimized) that open "https://www.google.com/" in a new window of edge. Is there anyway to do that with vbscript?